# Attaching to w3wp says "process does not have the expected debugging export table"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-debugging, coreclr, w3wp

The full error message is:

**Microsoft Visual Studio**

Unable to attach to the process. The debuggee memory space does not have the expected debugging export table.

Now, the only place i found this message is here: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/pal/prebuilt/corerror/mscorurt.rc

Core clr is installed on the machine but the application running in IIS is plain old 4.5 web forms.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: I would expect it doesn't have anything to do with CoreCLR. It's just that the closed source CLR shares code with the open source CoreCLR, so you only find code for the latter.

Comment: you may be right, didn't think of that...

Answer (score 0):

You would attach to dnx.exe process if you debug ASP.NET Core applications, since ASP.NET Core applications are standalone Console applications invoked through the dotnet runtime command. They are not loaded into an IIS worker process.

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/06/Publishing-and-Running-ASPNET-Core-Applications-with-IIS

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, what I am debugging is a plain old Asp.Net 4.5 WebForms application that lives in IIS.

I also found @svick's comment interesting that it may have nothing to do with core clr...

Comment: @Serban, The above steps are about how to debug the ASP.NET Core app, if it is the ASP.NET webforms app, I agree with svick's suggestion, it was not related to the CoreCLR. But for this issue, you need to collect more information like from the event view or others. Please also debug a simple web app deployed in the IIS, check it again.

Comment: afraid not. My colleague has reinstalled his os and now debugging works :|

Comment: If so, it is really hard to know the real reason for this issue, maybe you could uninstall and re-install the VS, test it again. To avoid that it is related to the CoreCLR, please also uninstall it firstly, and then you can debug your app before/after you reinstall it. At least, we could know that whether it is related to the VS setup or this specific package.